# Reverse each string in a structure of strings

Tags: c, recursion, structure

I've got to write a program that will take the contents of a text file and reverse each line using recursion. For example, this file:

```
abc def ghi
jkl mno pqr
```

should end up being:

```
ihg fed cba
rpq onm lkj
```

I figured the best way to do this would be to put the contents in a linked list and then reverse each line separately. The linked list part works just fine, except I'm not quite sure how to do the reversal part.. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NODE struct list

void reverse(void);

struct list {
        char array[20];
        struct list *next;
};


int main(void)
{
        reverse();
        return 0;
}


void reverse(void)
{
        NODE *p;
        p = head;

        while (p != NULL)
        {
                reverse(p->array + sizeof(p->array));
                printf("%d", p->array);
        }

        return;
}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile. I would recommend that you get a good C book and start studying from the basics... This will benefit you far more than someone just giving you the answer to what is likely an interview question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do an in-place string reversal using something like this:

```
void reverse_str(char* str)
{
    int len = strlen(str),i;
    for(i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - 1 - i];
        str[len - 1 - i] = c;  
    }
}
```

However, the above function is actually recursive, if you want to make it recursive, you can use binary recursion to work your way from the outer to the inner characters, using `len` to determine when to stop.

then, using your linked list, can do (edited to actually make this recursive...):

```
void reverse(struct Node* p)
{
    if(!p)
       return;

    reverse_str(p->array);
    printf("%s",p->array);
    reverse(p->next);        
}
```

Comment: tsk tsk tsk for providing code to what looks like an assignment.

Comment: @Nim: this probably whats in his book (if its half decent), just more readable, but I do agree I should have probably gone the non-"spoon feed" route, but that gives me an idea...

Answer (score 0):

i think, something like that. Size of array is hardcoded to 10 as in your example. Using recursion :

```
void reverse( struct list *p )
{
  if( p )
  {
    int i;
    reverse(p->next);
    for (i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
      char tmp=p->array[i];
      p->array[i]=p->array[i+10];
      p->array[i+10]=tmp;
    }
    p->array[19]=0; // to ensure 0 byte at string end
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As fas I understood, you have to use recursion. In this case, you do not need a linked list.
Here is a pseudo code to reverse a line, thus you can get the idea:

```
function reverse(text)
  if (text = empty) 
    return
  else
     call reverse(text but the first letter)
     print(first letter of text)
  endif
endfun
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem using recursion is just plain stupid. It is better to do it iteratively.

Anyway, here is some pseudo-code on how to do it:

```
/* Recursive function to print a string backwards */
print_reverse(char first_char, char *rest_of_string) {
  if (rest_of_string[0]) {
    /* First print the rest of the strin backwards... */
    print_reverse(rest_of_string[0], rest_of_string + 1);
  }
  /* ... then print the first character in the string */
  print first char
}

for each line {
  print_reverse(line[0], line + 1);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "iteratively".